# Run-time Error '1006': Unknown

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a list form in Microsoft Access 2007, and I'm trying to make a button that will search one of the fields for a given phrase. The problem is that the field I'm trying to search is a memo field, and I usually want to keep the records sorted (by a count field). This truncates my memo field to 255 characters and makes the rest of the field unsearchable. So, I've been been turning off the "OrderByOn" property of the form I'm searching (or setting "OrderBy" to "") during the Form_Open event of the search form, which appears to correctly unsort my data and makes the memo field fully viewable. However, when I try to search, I sometimes get the error "Microsoft Visual Basic Run-time Error '1006': Unknown" when it gets to the FindNext line. I think I get the error if the search term is not found in the first 255 characters of the records between the current record and the end of the recordset. This is the code for the search form:

```
    Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
        [Forms]![MyForm]![MySubform].[Form].OrderBy = ""
        '[Forms]![MyForm]![MySubform].[Form].OrderByOn = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Search_Click()
        Dim vDescription As String
        Dim r As Recordset

        vDescription = ""

        If Me![Description] <> "" Then vDescription = "[MyFieldName] LIKE('*' + '" & Me![Description] & "' + '*')"

        If Not (vDescription = "") Then
            Set r = [Forms]![MyForm]![MySubform].[Form].Recordset
    >       r.FindNext (vDescription)
            If r.NoMatch Then
                r.MoveFirst
                r.FindNext (vDescription)
                If r.NoMatch Then
                    MsgBox ("No match found.")
                    r.MoveFirst
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

I can't find any search results for this error message, which seems odd. Why am I getting an error? Am I using the recordset correctly? Should I be handling OrderBy/OrderByOn differently?

Comment: Anything in particular I should be looking for in vDescription? Right now it's `[MyFieldName] LIKE('*' + 'StuffITypedIn' + '*')`. And yeah, parentheses when I don't need them is a bad habit of mine. I got rid of them, same error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what's going on with your code.  Test this version to see if it sheds any light on the problem.

```
Private Sub Search_Click()
    Dim vDescription As String
    Dim r As DAO.Recordset

    vDescription = vbNullString ' not actually required '

    If Len(Me![Description] & vbNullString) > 0 Then
        vDescription = "[MyFieldName] LIKE '*" & _
            Me![Description] & "*'"
        Debug.Print "vDescription: " & vDescription
        Set r = [Forms]![MyForm]![MySubform].[Form].RecordsetClone
        r.FindNext vDescription
        If r.NoMatch Then
            r.MoveFirst
            r.FindNext vDescription
            If r.NoMatch Then
                MsgBox "No match found."
                r.MoveFirst
            End If
        End If
        Set r = Nothing
    End If
```

End Sub

Comment: The error still shows up and vDescription is now `[MyFieldName] LIKE('*StuffITypedIn*')`, but if I use RecordsetClone instead of Recordset it doesn't actually move to the next record when it finds a match.

Comment: I don't understand how you got those parentheses in `vDescription` using my code sample.  Meanwhile, with `RecordsetClone`, I think you would need to use the `.Bookmark` property to actually navigate records in the form: `Me.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark`  But that is sort of beside the point of what I was attempting; I was only interested is seeing whether we could avoid the error you reported.

Comment: My bad, I typed that line instead of copy/pasting because my real form names are much longer. Have fixed, now vDescription is `[MyFieldName] LIKE '*StuffITypedIn*'`. Error message still happens. Thanks for all your help; at this point I'm considering making a new query from the database, finding my search terms in that recordset, then matching up the ID fields to move to the correct record on my form.